# Angularjs login with headers Authentication

Tags: angularjs, authentication

```
$http({
    url: 'https://www.test.com/user/Api/Securelogin',
    method: "POST",
    header: {
        access_token : 'jjyzstmozj75',
        client_id : 'll_123_APP',
        client_secret : 'sdfxilxxsfd'
    },
    data : {
        username: username, 
        password: password
    }
}).success(function(response) {
    callback(response);
});
```

What I would like to get

> Accept application/json, text/plain, */*
>   Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
>   Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
>   Authorization   Basic **This place need to be changed**
>   Content-Length  36
>   Content-Type    application/json;charset=utf-8
>   Cookie  PHPSESSID=b5b7a9d95cD
>   Host    www.test.com
>   Referer https://www.test.com/newclip/
>   User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0
>   access_token    sdfsdfb9clyzsosdfsd
>   client_id   ll_123_APP
>   client_secret   dfgdf6j1l2dxsdf

What I get instead

> NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized

It is posting username password as json.
source :

```
{
    "username" : "abc",
    "password" : "4214"
}
```

Response is

```
{
    "username" : [
        "username or email cannot be blank."
    ],
    "password" : [
        "password cannot be blank."
    ]
}
```

What kind of issue is this?

Comment: Well, that can be a lot... First of all: is the username and/or password blank? The error clearly states that. Next: Why are you passing an access token during login with basic authorization on?  Please provide more background!

Comment: ----https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-authentication-example ---
I am using this module 
I want to put my headers  Authentications here how to put
<pre>
$http.post('https://www.test.com/user/Api/Securelogin',{ username: username, password: password })
                .success(function (response) {
                    callback(response);
            }); </pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$http.post('URL', { headers: {"Accept": "application/json","Content-Type": "application/json",'authorization': 'Basic eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5c'} ,
      params: {
        username: username,
        password:password
      }
    }).then(function(response){

    });
```

Comment: params is not working
The same code is working when i collecting data form server but login not working...

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
          $http({
            "method": "GET",
            "url":url + "",
            "data": data,
            "headers": { 'Authorization': '34444344444},

            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=UTF-8"
        })
```

Comment: where i will post username and password get will not work.

I am using this module please check.
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx

Comment: change method name from "GET" To "POST"

Comment: <code>Thanks for replay
I am using login module form here

https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-authentication-example

 My server expects

1. it have to be post method
2. it has 3 headers authentications :
headers: {
                    access_token : 'fcxjmozj75',
                    client_id : '123_APP',
                    client_secret : 'u06zzl2dxilxx'
                },
3. and username password

</code>

Comment: My last modified code is below

$http.post('https://www.test.com/user/Api/Securelogin',
                    { username: username, password: password },
                    {headers: {
                        access_token : 'sdfsdf9clyzstmozj75',
                        client_id : 'abc_123_APP',
                        client_secret : 'sdfsdf78tf6j1l2dxilxx'
                    }
            })
                .success(function (response) {
                    callback(response);
            });

Comment: here i should have a "contentType" dont know how to use. 
in console i am getting

Headers

Accept application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization Basic here should have code but missing
Content-Length 36
Content-Type application/json;charset=utf-8
Cookie PHPSESSID=9f4976e98764d11a29d38065f3c29e8c
Host www.test.com
Referer https://www.test.com/newclip/index.html
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0
access_token sdfsdfy4b9clyzstmsdf5
client_id sdff_123_APP
client_secret sdfdsf8tf6j1l2dsdfxx

Comment: in Post

JSON

  
 
password
 "3214"
 
username
 "don"
Source
{"username":"don","password":"3214"}

In response

{"username":["username or email cannot be blank."],"password":["password cannot be blank."]}

Thanks